# How to allow users to send emails only to specific domains?

Tags: email, remedyforce

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict our users from sending emails from Salesforce to any email domains other than our company's. We want to make sure that the users don't have the ability to send sensitive information to someone outside the organization.

Thank you in advance,
Lior.

Comment: This may be a good use of Email Relay, where you can have more visibility and control over emails going out from your org.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can write a `before trigger` on  `EmailMessage` to stop sending email to particular domain.

Below is the code example:

```
trigger stopSendingEmail on EmailMessage (before insert) {
    for(EmailMessage message: Trigger.New){
        if((message.ToAddress.contains('gmail')) || (message.ToAddress.contains('yahoo'))){
            message.addError('Email Alert: You are not allowed to send an email outside your organization. Please use another email address and try again');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Today I learned you can put a trigger on EmailMessage! This seems like a great strategy, but are there any limitations to this approach?

Comment: Apart from normal apex Governor Limits we might hit some email specific limitations. You can read more about it in below giving links...

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334302&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312442&type=1&mode=1

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm